# Dynamically adding new panel tab with existing panel tab

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

How can I add dynamic panel tab(ADF Component) with existing panel tab in ADF  like in any Internet Browser?

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic uishell  template to achieve that. it is available to download within jdev in check for updates

Comment: Hi Vik, thank you for ur reply I am using dynamic uishell template and there is one example also i have downloaded, adding new tab is working fine but one problem i m facing now to call adding new tab method at time of page load, if u have any solution please share.